# How can we check from email id, that the specific domain uses google apps for their email id?

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps

My project involves g+ sign as well as normal sign in. If the user uses g+ sign in, I am prompting user with some consent screen to access contacts. If the user is using normal flow with some gmail id(also business id created by google apps), then I want to show a button - **Import contacts from gmail** and on click I will prompt consent screen. If he is using not gmail based email id, then I won't show that button at all. **How can I find email id used is created by a google apps?**

For example:

Consider the business emails for an organization **'sense.com'** is created by google apps,and the mail id is say **'jerry@sense.com'**. Is there a way to find just from 'jerry@sense.com', the mail id created by google apps? So that I will show button.

Answer (score 0):

I used Google Asmin SDK to deal with Google Apps accounts.

```
var service = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "My Application"
                });

var list = await service.Users.Get("somebody@sense.com").ExecuteAsync();
```

This returns the Google user account details if it's a valid account. But you need Authorized credentials (result.Credential) as the OAuth example in [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) . Hope you are already familiar with that.

You can try more features with the adminSDK in [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. But is there any specific modules available for node.js / javascript to deal this specifically? Since the project is handled by nodejs

Comment: Try Admin sdk with Node js library https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/